# "is_selected" in custom entityType

Tags: symfony

ineeded my value fields of my options to use a different field than the `id`, so i wrote a custom `FormType` that simply overwrites `finishView` and changes all the `value` entries and the array keys of `$view->vars['choices']`:

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    foreach ($view->vars['choices'] as $choiceKey => $choice) {
        $choice->value = $choice->data->getAcmeKey();
        $view->vars['choices'][$choice->value] = $choice;
        unset($view->vars['choices'][$choiceKey]);
    }
    parent::finishView($view, $form, $options);
}
```

I then added a ViewTransformer to get back the id for that custom Key.
So far so good.

Now the Problem is that in my form, the active choice is not selected.
So if i set `data` to a certain value or bind an entity to the form setting the value, in the output it is not selected - probably because there is a `entity->getId() == option->vale` in the `EntityType`/`DoctrineType` but i fail to find it, nor solve that Problem.

Anyone any ideas?